# SSIS Script Component or Task to check File Line Terminators and Fail if NOT CRLF

Tags: ssis, etl

I'm a little new to using scripts for my ETL work and I couldn't find anything related to this other than to use a script to replace LF or CRLF with a value. Is it possible to use a script or something else to validate that my file uses CRLF line terminators only, and if it is anything but CRLF it fails the job.

I'm looking to fail this job so then I can report to the agency sending files that they need to follow specific format and so the only files loaded are CRLF files.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out a way to handle what I was asking. I ended up creating a script task before my Data flow to check the file to see if it contained "\r\n". With this I used two package variables and passed them through my script. Those variables were "FileName" (could be file path but I used the same name as what was being used in the package), "ErrorMessage" and "IsCrLf". The "IsCrLf" variable is a boolean variable which basically just checks to see if "\r\n" exists in the file. If not, the ErrorMessage will get populated and passed through to an e-mail alert.

Here is my code for my task:

```
public void Main()
    {
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(Dts.Variables["User::FileName"].Value.ToString()))
        {
            string s1 = r.ReadToEnd();
            string s2 = "\r\n";
            bool b = s1.Contains(s2);

            if (b)
            {
                Dts.Variables["User::IsCrLf"].Value = true;
            }

            else
            {
                Dts.Variables["User::ErrorMessage"].Value = Dts.Variables["User::FileName"].Value.ToString()+Environment.NewLine+"File does not contain the expected CRLF format.";
                Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Error", "File does not contain the expected CRLF format.", string.Empty, 0);
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            }
        }
    }
```